Getting an error: System.IO.FileLoadException Message: Could not load file or assembly 'MathNet.Numerics
I have been getting this error:
Error Type: System.IO.FileLoadException
Message: Could not load file or assembly 'MathNet.Numerics,
Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its
dependencies. Operation is not supported. (Exception from HRESULT:
0x80131515)

I am currently trying to run a command through the AddInManager in Revit and when I run my command I go through all of the correct steps however it then fails and I get this error, I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling MathNet.Numerics, I have also tried MathNet.Numerics.Signed and nothing seems to have worked. I have even copied the .dll files to the correct place and it just seems that nothing is working and I cannot seem to find anything that would be close to or specific to my case.
Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated, I am new to running Revit and AddInManager.
